# How to get all rows from database

Tags: php, mysql, plugins, wordpress

my site is  [Design Spicy](http://designspicy.com/)
I am trying to fetch custom table data in wordpress. There are 5 entries in my table, but it shows only first entry. why ?

I want to fetch all rows from table. any suggestions ?

```
function viewall22() 
{
      global $wpdb;
      $result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_savans");
      foreach($result as $row)    
      {
         $sitemap = '<?php echo $row[name];?>';
      }
}
```

Comment: please refer this, http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14239/wpdb-get-row-only-returns-a-single-row

Comment: `echo $row['name'];` ?

Comment: `function viewall22() 
{
      global $wpdb;
   $result = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM wp_savans");
   foreach($result as $row)    
   {
    $sitemap = '$row[name]';
  
 }
 return $sitemap;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
function viewall22() 
{
  global $wpdb;
  $sitemap = '';
  $result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_savans", ARRAY_A);
  foreach($result as $row)    
  {
     $sitemap .= $row[name];
  }
  echo $sitemap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function viewall22() 
{
  global $wpdb;
  $result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_savans", ARRAY_A);
  foreach($result as $row)    
  {
     $sitemap = '<?php echo $row[name];?>';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function viewall22() 
    {
          global $wpdb;
          $result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_savans");
          while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))                 
          {
             $sitemap = '<?php echo $row[name];?>';
          }
    }
```

refer to http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php for explanation

Answer (score 0):

For your more knowledge, You can refer this also! ( Alternative for @ **Vidhu Nair** )

```
function viewall22() 
{
      global $wpdb;
      $result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_savans");
      foreach($result as $key=>$row)    
      {
         $sitemap = $row->name; // Refer as get value by using 'Object'
      }
}
```

Thanks!